# Subquery returns more than 1 row mysql in select statement

Tags: mysql

I am executing below query to get various details from different tables

```
SELECT d.*,
(SELECT printers from tbl_client_contract c where c.client_id=d.id) as printers, 
(SELECT systems from tbl_client_contract c where c.client_id=d.id) as systems, 
(SELECT sales_date from tbl_client_contract c where c.client_id=d.id) as sales_date, 
(SELECT others from tbl_client_contract c where c.client_id=d.id) as others, 
(SELECT dispatch_to from dispatch c where c.client_id=d.id) as dispatch_to 
FROM `tbl_clients` d where status='1' and hide=0
```

But is displaying **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Can anyone help me where I am doing mistakes?

Comment: Every one of your subqueries returns more than one row, because I guess that all your clients have more than one printer, and more than one systems and so on. That's not the way to do it, you should look for a JOIN

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably rewrite this query to use a `JOIN` rather than the embedded `SELECT` statements you are using:

```
SELECT  d.*,
        c.printers,
        c.systems,
        c.sales_date,
        c.others,
        di.dispatch_to
  FROM  `tbl_clients` d
    LEFT JOIN tbl_client_contract c ON c.client_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN dispatch di ON di.client_id = d.id
  WHERE d.status = '1' AND d.hide = 0
```

Although logically it may make more sense to select from `tbl_client_contract` instead:

```
SELECT  cc.printers,
        cc.systems,
        cc.sales_date,
        cc.others,
        di.dispatch_to,
        c.*
  FROM  tbl_client_contract cc
    INNER JOIN `tbl_clients` c ON c. = cc.id
    LEFT JOIN dispatch di ON di.client_id = c.id
  WHERE d.status = '1' AND d.hide = 0
```

Comment: @ShankarVelan You're welcome. Could you mark this as the answer in that case?